# Jacobian transformation on $ \int\cdots \int \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n }{ \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 } } dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_n $

Tags: recurrence-relations, jacobian

**The exact question**:

> Consider the region $$
> U_n = \left \{
>  x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \geqslant 0, \sum \limits_{k=1}^n x_k ^2 \leqslant 1 \right \}
> . $$ Define $$
> B_n =  \idotsint\limits_{U_n} \left( \dfrac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n }{\sqrt{x_1 ^2 + x_2 ^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 }} \right) \ dx_1 \ dx_2 \ dx_3 \ \cdots \ dx_n $$

> Prove that $B_n$ satisfies the recurrence relation, $$\begin{equation}
> B_n = 
> \cases{
>   1 & n =1,2 \cr
>  \dfrac\pi{2n-2} B_{n-2} & n>2\cr
> }
> \end{equation}$$

**Context/Attempt**:

(It's trivial for $n=1$)

I was trying to solve a Jacobian transformation practice problem, which turns out to be the form of $B_2$. A simple transformation of $x_1 = r \cos \theta , x_2 = r\sin \theta \implies dx_1 dx_2 = r dr d\theta$ shows that $B_2 = 1$. For my own amusement, I extended it to 3-dimensions and used spherical coordinates, $$ (x_1, x_2, x_3) = (r \cos\theta \sin \phi , r \sin\theta \sin \phi , r \cos\theta) \implies dx_1 dx_2 dx_3 = r^2 \sin\phi \ dr d\phi d\theta   $$ to get $B_3 = \frac\pi4$.

Then I wondered if I can generalize this, which brought me to [this PDF](https://muleshko.faculty.unlv.edu/am_papers_pdf/n_d_polarcoordinates_note1.pdf).

By using the generalized Jacobian transformation, I get

$$ B_n=
\int_0^{\pi/2}  \int_0^{\pi/2}  \cdots \int_0^{\pi/2}  \int_0^1 \left[  \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin(\theta_k) + \sum_{m=2}^{n-1} \left(\cos\theta_{m-1} \prod_{k=m}^{n-1} \sin \theta_k\right) + \cos \theta_{n-1}      \right] \cdot 
\left[ \ r^{n-1}  \prod_{k=2}^{n-1} \sin^{k-1} \theta_k \ \right ] 
     dr  d\theta_1  d\theta_2  \cdots \ d\theta_{n-1} 
$$

I was hoping that all the variables $(r, \theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots, \theta_{n-1} ) $ are easily separable, but so far, I'm only able to take out $ \int_0^1 r^{n-1} \ dr = \frac1n $ from the huge expression.

By testing $n=3,4,5$ on Mathematica, I get $(B_3, B_4, B_5 ) = (\pi/4, \pi/6, \pi^2 /32) $

[image]

I then test for $n=6,7,8$ and I believed I've found a pattern (as stated above), but I'm nowhere near to a proof.

---

**Update 1** (Jan22 2023, 3.23pm GMT+0800): Looks like there's a geometric interpretation for this. [OEIS A087299](https://oeis.org/A087299).

Comment: For future reference, \idotsint appears as $\idotsint$, as a single object.  For instance, \idotsint\limits_{U_n} in display mode gives $$\idotsint\limits_{U_n}$$  I didn't change your post because it's a matter of taste, but I'd argue for its use.

Comment: I didn't know this LaTeX function existed. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: This is equivalent to $B_{n}=\frac{\pi^{n/2-1}\Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2})}{\Gamma(n)}$. By symmetries $B_n=n\idotsint\limits_{U_n}\frac{x_n}{r}d^nx$ is just $n$ times the volume of $U_n$ times the mean therein of $\cos\theta$, with $\theta\in[0,\,\pi/2]$ the name I chose for that angle. Since $U_n$ has volume $\frac{2(\sqrt{\pi}/2)^n}{n\Gamma(n/2)}$, I think you want to prove $\Bbb E\cos\theta=\frac{2^{n-1}}{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{\Gamma(n)}$.